# When saving a Facelet file containing characters with diacritics like "á" it get replaced by Mojibake like "Ã¡"

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, character-encoding

I would like to expose the following problem:

Development environment:

- Windows 7 Enterprise
- Eclipse Helios
- JDK 6u31
- JBoss 6

I am working in a web application in which you can introduce names with accents (through "inputText" controls). I am using Java Server Faces.

When I introduce these characters in a certain page (add_edit_station.xhtml), I can see (debugging the java code source associated to that page) that the character with accent ("á" for instance) is replaced with a strange character string ("Ã¡").

If I go to another page (`fare_product.xhtml`) and after that I return to add_edit_station.xhtml web page, the character with accent keeps ok in the java source code (in the correspond variable).

I think it must be something related to the JBoss configuration because if I close the web application and I open it again, the first time I go to the `add_edit_station.xhtml` web page the name with accent works correctly.

After trying to look for a solution I did the following actions:

- Eclipse configuration

  - In the project properties --> Resource, I set the text file encoding to UTF-8
  - In both pages ".xhtml" the UTF-8 encoding is defined through the tag
  - For every source code file ".java" that implements the logic of the pages I set the option "Default (determined from content: UTF-8) in Edit --> Set Encoding...
- JBOSS configuration

  - File "run.conf.bat". In the "java" call I set the parameters:
    -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 
    -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

I don't understand why the web behaves that way.

Comment: Did you also set *Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text File Encoding* to UTF-8?

Comment: Yes, I did. I forgot to mention this action in my description. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Okay. Well, then I've a hard time in understanding the problem. Perhaps you're misgrasping some basic terms/concepts. All I can suggest is to carefully go through http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html to understand better how it works "under the covers".